# Substantiviertes Gerundivum eines nichttrennbaren Verbs (»der zu Beurteilende«)

Tags: capitalization, nominalization

Es geht um folgenden Satz:

> 1 - Der zu Beurteilende wird gebeten, ins Zimmer 17 zu kommen.

- Ist hier das Wort »Beurteilende« groß oder klein zu schreiben?
- Was ist mit »zu«? Ist es richtig, »zu« kleinzuschreiben?
- Gibt es eine amtliche Regelung für das Substantivieren eines Gerundivums eines nichttrennbaren Verbs?

Ich vergleiche das mit:

> 2 - Der Alte wird gebeten, ins Zimmer 17 zu kommen.

Hier ist »Alte« ein substantiviertes Adjektiv. Setzt man dahinter ein geeignetes Substantiv (z.B. »Mann«) wird daraus ein Attribut dieses Substantivs, und das Adjektiv muss sich nicht mehr selber als Substantiv ausgeben, man schreibt es daher klein:

> 3 - Der alte Mann wird gebeten, ins Zimmer 17 zu kommen.

Auch zum Satz 1 kann man so einen Satz finden:

> 4 - Der zu beurteilende Mann wird gebeten, ins Zimmer 17 zu kommen.

Hier ist »zu beurteilende« ein Attribut, welches das Substantiv »Mann« näher beschreibt. Genau dieselbe Rolle hat auch »alte« im Satz 3. Es gibt aber zwei wichtige Unterschiede:

- **alte**
  nur ein Wort
  Adjektiv
- **zu beurteilende**
  zwei Wörter
  zu + Gerundivum (auch bekannt als »zu-Partizip«)

Klar scheint zu sein, dass die Weglassung des referenzierten Substantivs (Übergang von Satz 3 zu 2, bzw. von 4 zu 1) das Attribut substantiviert (also großgeschrieben) werden muss.

Unklar ist mir aber, ob das ganze Attribut dann großzuschreiben ist (*»Der Zu Beurteilende wird gebeten ...«*), oder ob es ausreicht, nur einen der beiden Bestandteile großzuschreiben, wobei sich dann die Frage stellt welchen (*»Der Zu beurteilende wird gebeten ...«* oder *»Der zu Beurteilende wird gebeten ...«*).

Einfacher wird es natürlich, wenn das Verb, von dem das Gerundivum abstammt, trennbar ist, denn dann wandert das »zu« ins Wort hinein, so dass es nur ein Wort gibt. Beispiel »ausbilden«:

> 5 - Der Auszubildende wird gebeten, ins Zimmer 17 zu kommen.

Aber wie genau ist die Substantivierung von Gerundiven von nichttrennbaren Verben geregelt?

Comment: Warum versuchst du dich nicht an *Der zu Alte wird gebeten, ins Zimmer 17 zu kommen*? Es ist zwar eine andere Verwendung von "zu", aber hier wird wohl kaum jemand auf die Idee kommen, das groß schreiben zu wollen.

Comment: @tofro: Ich bin ganz konkret von jemandem gefragt worden, wie man *»der zu Beurteilende«* schreibt. Der Fragesteller wollte das eigentlich so schreiben: *»Der Zu-Beurteilende«,* und fragte eigentlich, ob der Bindestrich richtig ist. Ich aber riet ihm stattdessen zu »der zu Beurteilende«. Nur kann ich leider keine offiziellen Regeln finden, um das auch zu belegen, und so ganz sicher bin ich mir auch  nicht, ob das richtig ist.

Comment: @tofro: Aber dein Beispiel ist eigentlich auch spannend. Wie sicher bist du dir, dass man das kleinschreibt? Woher nimmst du deine Sicherheit? Ich bin mir da nämlich gar nicht so sicher.

Comment: Der Bindestrich ist ziemlich sicher falsch. Auch wenn man den "Zum-Tode-Verurteilten" nach §43 wohl koppeln sollte. Möglicherweise würde man dann den "Zum-Tode-zu-Verurteilenden" so schreiben, aber nicht den "zu Verurteilenden"

Comment: Darf ich ein bisschen (ceterum censeo) mosern, dass die oben (mit-) gestellte Frage nach "amtlichen Regelungen" der Sache nicht angemessen ist? Sprachkultur ist nichts, was von Amtsstuben aus zu regeln wäre. (Versuche dieser Art aus deutscher Kultusministerialbürokratie würde ich ignorieren.) Und außerdem: wessen Ämter sollten das entscheiden? Deutschlands? Österreichs? Der Schweiz? Die UNESCO?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: [Der Rechtschreibrat](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com). Ich zitiere wörtlich von seiner Homepage: *»Grundlage der neuen deutschen Rechtschreibung ist das aus einem Regelteil und einem Wörterverzeichnis bestehende **amtliche Regelwerk.** Vom Rat für deutsche Rechtschreibung herausgegeben, fixiert es die **amtliche Norm** und bildet damit gleichsam den „Urmeter“ der neuen deutschen Rechtschreibung.«*

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ebenfalls amtlich (weil von der österreichischen Bundesregierung herausgegeben), aber nur für österreichisches Deutsch gültig: [Das österreichische Wörterbuch (ÖWB)](https://www.oewb.at/). Ich zitiere aus [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Österreichisches_Wörterbuch): *»Das Österreichische Wörterbuch repräsentiert als Wörterbuch (Rechtschreibwörterbuch) das für Österreich gültige **amtliche Regelwerk** der deutschen Sprache«*

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann ...es ist gut - wir haben's gehört ... ;)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast ach du meine Nase, dieses Zitat vom Rat sagt ja wohl alles. Keine weiteren Fragen. Der bezichtigte zu urst beteiligte chuldet hundert Talent dem Kläger im Namen des Volkes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich sehe keinerlei Veranlassung, das "zu" bei der Substantivierung gross zu schreiben.

Wikipedia sagt, es gäbe keine Regel, aber eine "stillschweigende Übereinkunft", wie das Gerundivum zu bilden sei, läßt sich über die Grossschreibung nicht aus, aber zeigt in den Beispielen deutlich, wie es zu schreiben ist:

> Möglich ist aber auch die Substantivierung des zu-Partizips (das zu Lobende und das zu Tadelnde), wobei die Orthografie nicht amtlich geregelt ist, aber wohl weiter Konsens besteht, dass, wo nicht inkorporiert, weiterhin getrennt geschrieben und nicht gekoppelt wird, also „das zu Beobachtende“ und „das Zuzuziehende“[4]. Im Deutschen sind auch einige Gerundive „als Substantivierungen lexikalisiert, z.B. der/die Auszubildende“[5].

Die Quelle [4] verweist auf "Duden, richtiges und gutes Deutsch", das ich leider hier grade nicht zur Hand habe.

Das sollte sowohl deine Frage nach einer amtlichen Regelung, als auch nach der gängigen Praxis beantworten.

Answer (score -2):

> "Klar scheint zu sein, dass die Weglassung des referenzierten Substantivs (...) das Attribut substantiviert (also großgeschrieben) werden muss."

Das Sehen ich nicht so.

Wegen der häufigen Verwendung von *der* als Artikel könnte man geneigt sein, alles darauf folgende als Substantiv zu lesen. Es könnte aber auch ein Pronomen sein, so wie "alles" im vorigen Satz, wobei ich "folgende" bewusst und wohl richtig klein schreibe, ähnlich wie "Das Sahen" im ersten Satz, wobei ich das Verb *sehe (ich)* aber witziger Weise falsch als Substantiv infinitiv "Sehen" geschreiben habe.

Klingt dann so gesehen etwas schräg und der Vortrag bzgl. "Der Alte" ist nicht einfach von der Hand zu weisen. Während bei *alt-* regulär mit *-e* flektiert wird, grundlegend *Er ist alt, der Alte*, geht es im Gegenteil nicht

> ** Er ist zu beurteilend*

> *Er ist zu beurteilen*.

Da stimmt also was nicht.

Es genügt auch nicht schlicht von einem Passiv-Partizip auszugehen, insofern fraglich bleibt, was es mit den Präfixen auf sich hatte. Doch bevor ich mich um Kopf und Kragen rede bei dem Versuch es als trennbares Verb auszulegen (Sie behelfen ihm? Sie helfen ihm bei?) oder einem Kognat von English "to be" beizukommen (* Er, über den zu urteilen *ist*?) , möchte ich behaupten, dass vermutlich mehrere Lösungen möglich sind und die Sache schlicht auf "der zu Beurteilende" beruhen kann.

Comment: Ich kann dir nicht folgen. Die Wortfolge *»Das Sehen ich nicht so«* enthält kein Verb. Das ist kein korrekter Satz. Damit kann man genau gar nichts belegen. Auch der Rest deines Postings wirkt auf mich etwas wirr. Möchtest du diesen Beitrag vielleicht nochmal überarbeiten? Ich verstehe ganz einfach nicht, was du damit sagen willst.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Let's continue this discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118287/der-zu-beurteilende). Lies dir vorher bitte noch mal den zweiten Absatz durch bzgl. "Sehen".

Comment: Ich habe nicht vor zu chatten. Siehe https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1617/1487

Comment: "Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post" soviel dazu

Comment: Nochmal mit etwas abstand betrachtet; hoffentlich möchtest du doch darauf eingehen. 1. Der erste Satz ist im wesentlichen eine Aussage meinerseits. Für Kritik an meinem Sprachstil kannst du gern auf meine Erklärung im Chat eingehen, oder es eben lassen. 2. "das Folgende" wäre laut wiki/Partizip wohl groß zu Schreiben. Vermutlich wird "..., alles darauf Folgende" demnach entgegen meiner Behauptung in der Regel ebenso groß geschrieben. Das hatte ich nicht bedacht, aber wenn das kein klarer Fehler ist, sondern meiner Erklärung wegen eher verwirrend, dann sind wir uns ja einig.

Comment: ... Was dar an zweitens "schräg" "klingt" bedürfte sicherlich einer genaueren Erklärung, wie und warum. Vielleicht wäre eine Auseinandersetzung über den einfacheren Fall "das Folgende" auch zugänglich. Das habe ich aber wie gesagt übersehen und war auch nicht mein Ziel. Könnte glatt in Arbeit ausarten.

Comment: 3. Fand ich bei wiki/Gerundium einige Hinweise auf dialektale Formen, die insbesondere auch einen Wechsel ähnlich wie von mir besprochen zwischen *-end* und *-en*, bzw. auch *-enne* betreffen und darüber hinaus teils auch *zu* anführen, aber aeben auch Einflüsse von Partizipien zeigen. 4. Gehst du ja schon voreingenommen an die Sache ran und bist an einer ehrlichen Antwort mit einem erkennbarennen Lösungsweg kaum interessiert, wenn es bloß gilt, Zweifel auszuräumen, dann aber die Meinung, man könne es halten wie 'ne Maurerkeller, doch als Wirr erachtest.